# Using xinput vibration with java

Tags: java, dll

I need to use vibration for my java game, which is only available through xinput since I use xbox controllers. How can I achieve this with jna? I've never worked with dlls before so any help is appreciated. I looked at some tutorials but I haven't found anything about using structures (specifically XINPUT_VIBRATION vibration;) and such.

This is what I want to do in the DLL:

```
XINPUT_VIBRATION vibration;
ZeroMemory( &vibration, sizeof(XINPUT_VIBRATION) );
vibration.wLeftMotorSpeed = 32000; // use any value between 0-65535 here
vibration.wRightMotorSpeed = 16000; // use any value between 0-65535 here
XInputSetState( i, &vibration );
```

The above is taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417001(v=vs.85).aspx#setting_vibration_effects

Thanks!

Comment: An alternative to using Java Native Access is to use the JINPUT library with which you can control an Xbox controller https://github.com/jinput/jinput

Comment: I already use jinput, however it does not support vibration on the xbox controller since it uses directinput instead of xinput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you world, this library works:
https://github.com/StrikerX3/JXInput